# What makes a point on path of reflected light (while forming image) visible?

Tags: visible-light, reflection, geometric-optics, vision

The path of light is not visible in vaccum,but only the source(reflecting surface) of light is visible to us. But in case of image formation,  for example from a concave mirror, we see the image at the point of intersection of rays. That point lies in the path of intersecting rays.

As we can see the image, it is similar in saying that a point on path of light is visible. Why? What makes us see the point where light rays intersect?
Or why we see image at a point where light is not reflected but intersected?

Comment: Do you have the same doubt in the case of a standard flat mirror in which the image looks behind the surface instead?